# Radius of convergence of $\sum \frac{n!}{n^n} a_n z^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I'm trying to prove that the radius of convergence of $\sum \frac{n!}{n^n} a_n z^n$ is $eR$ when $R>0$ is the radius of convergence of $\sum a_n z^n$.

I can easily obtain that the radius of convergence of $\sum \frac{n!}{n^n} a_n z^n$ is $\ge eR$ thanks to a more general rule. But how can I manage to get the equality (without using Stirling formula if possible)?

Using Striling Formula, one can prove that since $\frac{n!}{n^n} a_n \sim \frac{a_n}{e^n}\sqrt{2\pi n}z^n$, $\sum \frac{n!}{n^n} a_n z^n$ has same radius than $\sum \frac{a_n}{e^n}\sqrt{2\pi n} z^n$ which has same radius than $\sum \frac{a_n}{e^n}z^n$ which is $eR$.

Comment: You'll probably end up proving a Stirling-type-formula in any case, so why not use it?

Comment: @b00nheT I also want to know if student that do not know Stirling formula can prove the equality.

Comment: If you applied the root test, you could get that $\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}$ is the exponential of something which is *almost* a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 \log x \, dx$ except for the fact it's an improper integral.  Still, you should be able to get an inequality on the sum based on that which might be good enough to conclude the limit is $\frac{1}{e}$.  (And if you could assume $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ were a convergent sequence then the ratio test would be easier.)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\lim _{n\to \infty }{a_n\over a_{n+1}}=R$$therefore $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{{n!\over n^n}a_n\over {(n+1)!\over (n+1)^{n+1}}a_{n+1}}{=\lim_{n\to \infty } {1\over n+1}{ (n+1)^{n+1}\over n^n}\lim_{n\to \infty }{a_n\over a_{n+1}}\\=\lim_{n\to \infty } { (n+1)^{n}\over n^n}\lim_{n\to \infty }{a_n\over a_{n+1}}\\=eR}$$